# simple client/server application exchanging msg

Tags: java

my question here is how to exchange msg between clients ?
how can i develop method for Text messages should be exchanged between them until the client sends "BYE" or "QUIT".
This is the code for the server

```
public SocketServer(int port) {
    this.port = port;
}

public void start() throws IOException {
    System.out.println("Starting the socket server at port:" + port);
    serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);

    //Listen for clients. Block till one connects

    System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
    Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

    //A client has connected to this server. Send welcome message
    sendWelcomeMessage(client);
}

private void sendWelcomeMessage(Socket client) throws IOException {
    BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(client.getOutputStream()));
    writer.write("Hello. You are connected to a Simple Socket Server. What is your name?");
    writer.flush();       
    writer.close();
}
```

and this for the client

```
public SocketClient(String hostname, int port){
    this.hostname = hostname;
    this.port = port;
}

public void connect() throws UnknownHostException, IOException{
    System.out.println("Attempting to connect to "+hostname+":"+port);
    socketClient = new Socket(hostname,port);
    System.out.println("Connection Established");
}

public void readResponse() throws IOException{
    String userInput;
    BufferedReader stdIn = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socketClient.getInputStream()));

    System.out.println("Response from server:");
    while ((userInput = stdIn.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(userInput);
    }
}
```

Comment: looks like you need a while loop somewhere waiting for the user to send the "BYE" or "QUIT" to exit the loop

Answer (score 0):

new ServerSocket(hostname, port) creates a new socket which is bound to the 'port' and can only accept new connections. It is not used for data communication.

When new client connects to the server, ServerSocket.accept() would return a completely new Socket object which is then used for communication with the client (possibly via Reader/Writer).

At this moment ServerSocket is still perfectly valid and calling accept() again on it is completely independent of the lifecycle of new client Socket object.

If you call ServerSocket.accept() again it will wait for next client and then next and so on.

Just make sure at some point in time you "close()" client connections returned from accept().

Important notion is "blocking" calls. accept() won't allow execute next line of code until new client connected. readLine() won't allow execute next line of code until some data has been sent by the other party.

If you want to enable serving of several clients at the same time, create a pool of threads and use next available thread to run protocol handler for a new client. Then "blocking" read/write operations would be isolated from main code in the thread and main code can call "accept()" again.

E.g. simple extension to your server code would allow it to serve multiple client requests:

```
System.out.println("Waiting for clients...");
while(!done) {
    final Socket client = serverSocket.accept();

    new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        try {
            sendWelcomeMessage(client);
        } finally {
            client.close();
        }
    }.start();
}

sendWelcomeMessage:
  send welcome
  read input
  if input=="bye" then done=true
```

Basic explanation and example which is almost the same as your code can be found at the Oracle site: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/networking/sockets/clientServer.html#later

You also should read good tutorial on multi-threading. Try this one: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

Comment: sorry but im asking how could 2 clients msg each other until one of them send Bye or Quit

Answer (score 0):

Months ago , i have writing this code (APP Chat java ) in `Netbeans` (It works for me) , I wish it helps you.

**Server part**

```
/**
 * Server
 * @author Zied
 */
public class ChatServer  implements Runnable ,ActionListener{

    private JFrame jfrm;
    private ServerSocket serverSocket;
    private Socket socketClient;
    private  ObjectInputStream ois;
    private  ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private JTextArea  jta;
    private JScrollPane jscrlp;
    private JTextField jtfInput;
    private JButton jbntSend;

    public ChatServer() {

       jfrm=new JFrame("Chat Server");
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setSize(300,320);
        Thread myThread =new Thread(this);
        myThread.start();
        jta= new JTextArea(15, 15);
        jta.setEditable(false);
        jta.setLineWrap(true);
        jscrlp=new JScrollPane(jta);
        jtfInput=new JTextField(15);
        jtfInput.addActionListener(this);
        jbntSend=new JButton("Send");
        jbntSend.addActionListener(this);
        jfrm.getContentPane().add(jscrlp);
        jfrm.getContentPane().add(jbntSend);
        jfrm.getContentPane().add(jtfInput);
        jfrm.setVisible(true);


    }

    /*****   main   ******/
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ChatServer();
            }
        });

    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)
    {

        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Send")|| ae.getSource() instanceof JTextField)
        {
            try {
                oos.writeObject(jtfInput.getText());
                jta.setText(jta.getText()+"You say :"+jtfInput.getText()+"\n");
                jtfInput.setText("");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }

    public void run() {
       try
       {
           serverSocket = new ServerSocket(4444);
           socketClient =serverSocket.accept();
           String s= String.valueOf( serverSocket.getLocalPort());
           oos=new ObjectOutputStream(socketClient.getOutputStream());
           ois=new ObjectInputStream(socketClient.getInputStream());
           while(true)
           {
               Object input=ois.readObject();
               jta.setText(jta.getText()+"Client says :"+ (String)input +"\n");

               if (input.equals("bye"))
               {
                   System.exit(0);
               }
           }


       }catch(IOException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();

       }
    }
}
```

**Client part :**

```
/**
 * Client
 * @author Zied
 */
public class ChatClient  implements Runnable ,ActionListener{

    private JFrame jfrm;
    private Socket socket;
    private  ObjectInputStream ois;
    private  ObjectOutputStream oos;
    private JTextArea  jta;
    private JScrollPane jscrlp;
    private JTextField jtfInput;
    private JButton jbntSend;

    public ChatClient() {

       jfrm=new JFrame("Chat Client");
        jfrm.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        jfrm.setLayout(new FlowLayout());
        jfrm.setSize(300,320);
        Thread myThread =new Thread(this);
        myThread.start();
        jta= new JTextArea(15, 15);
        jta.setEditable(false);
        jta.setLineWrap(true);
        jscrlp=new JScrollPane(jta);
        jtfInput=new JTextField(15);
        jtfInput.addActionListener(this);
        jbntSend=new JButton("Send");
        jbntSend.addActionListener(this);
        jfrm.getContentPane().add(jscrlp);
        jfrm.getContentPane().add(jbntSend);
        jfrm.getContentPane().add(jtfInput);
        jfrm.setVisible(true);

    }


    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO code application logic here

          SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                new ChatClient();
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
     try
       {
          socket=new Socket("localhost",4444);
           oos=new ObjectOutputStream(socket.getOutputStream());
           ois=new ObjectInputStream(socket.getInputStream());

           while(true)
           {
               Object input=ois.readObject();
               jta.setText(jta.getText()+"Server says :"+ (String)input +"\n");
               if (input.equals("bye"))
               {
                   System.exit(0);
               }
           }


       }catch(IOException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();
       }catch (ClassNotFoundException e)
       {
           e.printStackTrace();

       }    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {

        if (ae.getActionCommand().equals("Send")|| ae.getSource() instanceof JTextField)
        {
            try {
                oos.writeObject(jtfInput.getText());
                jta.setText(jta.getText()+"You say:"+jtfInput.getText()+"\n");
                jtfInput.setText("");
            } catch (IOException e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: can i use more than one client from different pcs ?